# How to append rows in Excel Binary Worksheet (xlsb)

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl, xlsb, pyxlsb

I tried using `openpyxl` library to read and write data in excel. But later did I know that I need to manipulate an excel binary worksheet. `openpyxl` doesn't support `xlsb`.

Is there any other libraries that I can use to be able to read and write data in `xlsb` without changing any format of the excel?

The requirement is, as much as possible:

1. Append data at the last row (Don't rewrite the whole data as it will affect the runtime of script).
2. Don't convert the `xlsb`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `xlwings` library. Image will be kept and I can work with .xlsb.